# Overlapping dates specifically within 10 day period of each date

Tags: sql, sap-iq

I am trying to find overlapping dates within 10-days of the `FROM_DATE` for the same `PERSON_ID` but that occurred under a different `MANAGER_ID` OR `SHIFT_ID`. This is missing a number of dates which would show because they all fall 10-days before an instance where there is a different `MANAGER_ID` OR `SHIFT_ID`.

I created a `DAYS_TABLE` with the `SET_DATE` (`FROM_DATE`) and `TEN_DAYS`, which is 10-days from the `SET_DATE`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
F.*
FROM #MAIN_TABLE F
INNER JOIN #DAYS_TABLE O
ON (F.PERSON_ID = O.PERSON_ID)
AND(F.ORDER_NBR != O.ORDER_NBR)
AND (NOT((F.MANAGER_ID = O.MANAGER_ID) OR
         (F.SHIFT_ID = O.SHIFT_ID)))

WHERE (F.FROM_DATE BETWEEN O.SET_DATE AND O.TEN_DAYS
);
```

I expect to see all instances where there is a `PERSON_ID` with date overlaps (10 days forward) for either a different `SHIFT_ID` or different `MANAGER_ID`. This would include all dates that maybe under the same `SHIFT_ID` or `MANAGER_ID`  but fall within the 10-days where there is a difference.

```
PER_ID  SHFT_ID MGR_ID  FROM    
1   A   U1  1/1/2019    
2   A   U1  1/1/2019    
1   A   U2  1/12/2019   
2   B   U2  1/12/2019   
1   B   U3  1/11/2019   


PER_ID  SHFT_ID MGR_ID  FROM    10_DAYS
1   A   U2  1/12/2019   1/22/2019
1   B   U3  1/11/2019   1/21/2019
```

Comment: please add some sample input and output data

Comment: I'm totally lost.  Where do the dates 1/22/2019 and 1/21/2019 come from?  They are not in your original data.

Comment: It’s 10 days forward from the from date. I set this in the days table. Anyway I may now have an answer by gathering the order number and the overlapping order number side by side that meet the criteria mentioned above. Sorry if this was not clear.

Comment: The names of the columns in your sample data (PER_ID, SHFT_ID, etc.) do not match those in your question, nor is it clear what that data is.

Comment: John, those names refer to shift id and person id. The data in this regards is for various scenarios occurring where there overlaps which means a date occurs within a 10 day window of a prior date. The scenarios would be a different shift id or different manager id to the prior date. I have resolved the issue but I appreciate the question. Have a great day.